# Set up A4 Document with printing borders in Adobe Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am quite new to Illustrator and would like to create my new CV using Illustrator CC. Like in Word, I would like to have a border so that when my CV is printed, the text etc. is not to close to the edge of the paper. However, I don't know how to create a standard sized border in Illustrator CC for DIN A4. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new document with papersize A4 and set the required border with the guides and place your content inside it.